# C#: assigning text and value to combobox member

Tags: c#, text, combobox, valuemember

I think i knew how to do this once upon a time but I can't figure it out right now. I'm trying to assign a list item in a combo box that has an associated value. Reason being is because i am populating it with a list of names from a database but I want it to store the primary key as a value so that I can call it directly in a subsequent query. For example, you select a name from a list of supervisors which will store the primary key for that supervisor in a variable for use in an event that will list all employees that have that key assigned to them as a supervisor. That make sense? Pretty standard. Here's what I have that is loading just the text portion of the names in:

The query:

```
static string sql = "select rtrim(elname),rtrim(efname) from employee where pos_id = 2";
```

The code that populates the list:

```
try
            {
                conn.Open();
                //determine how many records affected/returned              
                int records = dbAdapter.Fill(results); //fills the datatable with results and returns the number of records

                if (records > 0)
                {
                    //do something with the results (stored in the datatable)
                    foreach (DataRow dr in results.Rows)
                    {
                        cboSupervisor.Items.Add(dr[0] + ", " + dr[1]);

                    }
                    cboSupervisor.Sorted = true;
                }
            }
            catch { }
```

This fills the dropdown with lastname, firstname

Answer (score 3):

The best way is create a class containing the information you want to display and the one you want to keep, then specialize  ToString():

```
    public class ComboItem : object
    {
        protected String    name;
        ....
        ....
        protected int   id;

        public ComboItem(String name, int id)
        {
            this.name= name;

            this.id = id;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return name;
        }

    };
```

Comment: like on the web where you have a select box, it displays one thing but holds a value. im looking to do the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a ComboBoxItem, use the Content Property to set the name, and use the Tag Property to set the Value?  Then add the ComboBoxItem to your ComboBox's Items collection?